# Extjs : Tree structure is not getting displayed

Tags: json, extjs, extjs4

Am trying to create a simple tree structure. Am trying to make the structure by using json data in the store.

Here is my view formTree.js

```
Ext.define('TestMVC.view.form.formTree', {
extend: 'Ext.form.FormPanel',
alias: 'widget.formTree',
itemId: 'form',
renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
requires: ['Ext.form.field.Text', '*', 'Ext.tip.*',  'Ext.tree.*','Ext.data.*','Ext.tip.*'],
layout: {
    type: 'vbox',
    padding: 20
}, //******************************
//bodyStyle: 'background-image:url(../images/eggplant.jpg)!important',
initComponent: function () {
    //        this.addEvents('create');

    var required = '<span style="color:red;font-weight:bold" data-qtip="Required">*</span>';
    Ext.QuickTips.init();
    Ext.apply(this, {
        activeRecord: null,
        xtype:'treepanel',
        store: new Ext.data.TreeStore({
       proxy: {
            type: 'ajax',
          url: 'DataService/tree.json',
          reader: {
              type: 'json'

          }
        },
        root: {
            text: 'Ext JS',
            id: 'src',
            expanded: true
        },
        folderSort: true,
        sorters: [{
            property: 'text',
            direction: 'ASC'
        }] }),
        viewConfig: {
            plugins: {
                ptype: 'treeviewdragdrop'
            }
        },
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        height: 300,
        width: 250,
       , title: 'Files'
        useArrows: true,
        dockedItems: [{
            xtype: 'toolbar',
            items: [{
                text: 'Expand All',
                handler: function(){

                tree.expandAll();
                }
            }, {
                text: 'Collapse All',
                handler: function(){
                    tree.collapseAll();
                }
            }]
     }]

 });

    this.callParent();

}

});
```

And the json data in tree.json is as follows.

```
 { text: 'Maths', id: 'mathDept', children: [
    { text:'X1', id: 'x1', leaf: true },
    { text:'X2', id: 'x2', leaf: true}
]
},
{ text: 'Biology', id: 'bioDept', children: [
    { text: 'Y1', id: 'y1', leaf: true},
    { text: 'Y2', id: 'y2', leaf: true}
]
},  
{ text: 'English', id: 'engDept',  children: [
    { text: 'Z1', id: 'z1', leaf: true},
    { text: 'Z2', id: 'z2', leaf: true},
    { text: 'Z3', id: 'z3', leaf: true}             
]
}
```

On running this I get the error cannot read property dom  of null. Please help.

Comment: Maybe you can attach a screenshot?

Comment: Only the text expand all and collapse all is getting displayed. Nothing else is shown

Comment: Data in `tree.json` must be an array of objects. Is it so?

Comment: Nope still the tree isn't getting displayed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that data is incorrectly formatted. That must be an array:

```
[
    { text: 'Maths', id: 'mathDept', children: [
        { text:'X1', id: 'x1', leaf: true },
        { text:'X2', id: 'x2', leaf: true}
    ]
    },
    { text: 'Biology', id: 'bioDept', children: [
        { text: 'Y1', id: 'y1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Y2', id: 'y2', leaf: true}
    ]
    },  
    { text: 'English', id: 'engDept',  children: [
        { text: 'Z1', id: 'z1', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z2', id: 'z2', leaf: true},
        { text: 'Z3', id: 'z3', leaf: true}             
    ]
    }
]
```

Comment: Nope still the tree isn't getting displayed

Comment: So was my answer correct? If you marked it as resolved - I think that yes :)

Comment: Yup it was. Thank You